# NuSOAP - Function parameters don't map correctly

Tags: php, soap, parameters, nusoap

I'm writing a web service using NuSOAP in PHP. To test it, I have written both a server and a client. On the server end, I register the function like so:

```
$server->register(
    "testFunction",
    array("param1" => "xsd:string", "param2" => "xsd:string"),
    array("result" => "xsd:string"),
    "http://localhost/testApp"
);
```

And on the client looks like this:

```
require_once("./lib/nusoap.php");

$client = new soapclient("http://localhost/testApp/server.php");
$function = $_GET["function"];
unset($_GET["function"]);
$result = $client->call($function, $_GET);

echo "<pre>". print_r($result, true) ."</pre>";
```

When I call it like

```
http://localhost/testApp/client.php?function=testFunction&param1=value1&param2=value2
```

it works fine, but if I switch param1 and param2 and say

```
http://localhost/testApp/client.php?function=testFunction&param2=value2&param1=value1
```

then param1 gets the value `value2` and param2 gets the value `value1`. So obviously, it just goes by the order of the parameters, not the names.

I figured that since I registered the function with specific parameter names and then called the function, specifying those parameter names, that they would be assigned accordingly.

Am I missing something? What's the point of specifying the parameter names if they will just be thrown out and assigned in whatever order you entered them? Is there a way to make it so that I can enter the parameters in any order and have them map correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe go for a default map in the client:

```
    $default = array(
        'param1' => '',
        'param2' => 'test',
    );
    $params = $defaults;
    foreach ( $_GET as $param_name => $param_value ) {
        if ( isset( $params[ $param_name ] ) ) $params[$param_name] = $param_value;
    }
    $client->call( $function, $params );
```

Simple hack, even though it doesnt "really" answer your questions.

One note, the url you're passing to the client MUST be a SOAP WSDL if you expect the client to know anything about the format of the calls being made. Is yours ? ( It's been a long time I've used nuSoap, but i recall simply adding "?wsdl" param to the server url was enough to have the server respond with a valid wsdl )

Comment: Not a bad idea, but it would require a bit more for me. There are many functions that can be called, with different parameters in different orders, so I would have to do something like a switch statement and lay out the default parameters for each function. Also, the client that I wrote is just for my own testing. I will not be providing any client to our customers, since I think that pretty much defeats the purpose of using SOAP. They will need to write their own client to consume the web service.